# AR.js ES6 (@ar-js-org/ar.js) npm gives "Assertion failed: console.assert" error in console

Tags: aframe, webpack-5, ar.js

I am looking for some guidance. I have implemented AR.js via npm (ES6 - @ar-js-org/ar.js) import to build my app via webpack 5, everything seems to be imported ok; however, when running test i am getting an "Assertion failed: console.assert" error in console.
**My console initialization tracing looks like this:**

```
*"A-Frame Version: 1.3.0 (Date 2022-02-04, Commit #cc3516ce)
aframe-master.js:71837 THREE Version (https://github.com/supermedium/three.js): ^0.137.0
aframe-master.js:71839 WebVR Polyfill Version: ^0.10.12
aframe-ar.js:1 Assertion failed: console.assert
aframe-ar.js:1 Assertion failed: console.assert
aframe-ar.js:1 Assertion failed: console.assert
aframe-ar.js:1 AR.js 3.4.1 - trackingBackend: artoolkit
aframe-ar.js:1 ARToolkit 0.2.0
aframe-ar.js:1 [ARController] ARToolkit initialized
aframe-ar.js:1 [ARController] Camera params loaded with ID 0
aframe-ar.js:1 [ARController] Got ID from setup 0
aframe-ar.js:1 actual source dimensions 1023 767
aframe-ar.js:1 source orientation landscape
aframe-ar.js:1 actual source dimensions 1023 767
aframe-ar.js:1 source orientation landscape"*
```

Did anybody came accross this issue? is there a standard approach to fix the "Assertion failed: console.assert" ? I notice as well that a live example is experiencing the same issue ([https://thauska.github.io/peticov-ar/#/ar](https://www.stackoverflow.com/)) It is dated from Oct 31, 2021 so it is a bit old but exactly the same issue in the console.

If any one would have an idea on where to start to troubleshoot, maybe tweaks in webpack output(?) , I am a scratching my head on this one! :) Any little bit of info will help. In advance thank you very much!

I am not very familiar with the inner workings of the @ar-js-org/ar.js, so I am not sure where to start in the troubleshooting. Issues occur like models are off set of the marker but register x,y,z = 0. I imported the basic example from the doc. barebone i think the "Assertion failed: console.assert" result in different issues.